# Query in Access with a "contains" between columns

Tags: ms-access

I need a query in Access with the following:

If Column2, Cell("B1") = "A1" and 
Column 1, Cell ("A1")= "B1_A1_DTTROB" 
THEN Col3 **NEEDS TO SHOW** "Contains" or "Correct"

Thanks

Comment: Access doesn't have Cells or columns as such, it has fields and records. Post up the field names and the query you have tried and you might get some assistance...

Answer (score 0):

As @Minty said - Access understands fields and records. It hasn't got a clue about cells, columns or rows.  You can, if you must, think of a field as a column and a record as a row - but you will more than likely get corrected every time you say it out loud.

Saying that, I can see you're trying to compare your first field with the second field on the same record and if it's a match return the text.

```
SELECT  IIF(Column2 = [Column 1],"Contains","Correct") AS Col3 
FROM    MyTableName
```

This query will return a table containing a single field called `Col3`.  It will have the same number of records as your original table as it compares the two fields on each record.

To return other fields from your table just add them to the `Select` clause separated by a comma:
`Select Column2, [Column 1], ....`

Field names can contain spaces, but you have to wrap the field name in square brackets `[]`.  You can also use reserved words in fields, but again wrap them in square brackets `[Name]`.... using spaces or reserved words can causes problems further down the line, so easier to use `Column1` rather than `[Column 1]` and `strName` rather than `Name`.

In the field properties in the table design view there is a `Caption` property that lets you give the field an alias name, but I find this confusing when writing queries in SQL View - Design view will show the correct field name.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Properly speaking, what i need is to verify if the value (text) in field 2 is included in the value (text) of field 1. I mean, if field 1 = "B1_A1_DTTROB" and field 2= "A1", this A1 of the field 2 is included partially in the field 1. And if so, field 3 is "contains". Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah, ok.  I get you now. You'll need something like [INSTR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/instr-function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b).  I can't test at the moment - change the `IIF` statement in my answer to, I _think_, something like `IIF(INSTR([Field 1],[Field 2])>0,"Contains","Correct")`.  With your example the `INSTR` would return 4 as the _A_ in _A1_ is the fourth character in Field 1 - this is greater than 0, so "Contains" is returned.